# how does ~/git-credentials file look like?

Tags: password, git

Let's say I have a git repository for e.g. -

https://salsa.debian.org/shirishag75-guest/gradle-build-script-

Now in my system I have -

```
:~/games/gradle-build-script-/.git$ cat config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://salsa.debian.org/shirishag75-guest/gradle-build-script-.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Now I want to have my git username and password using https only authentication. How do I do that ?

The answer to that is [~/git-credentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store) . Can anybody share how it looks like or how it should look like ?

I tried to look at -

```
$ git config credential.helper --help
$
```

Doesn't tell me anything :(

Look forward to have some more info. maybe with a made-up example :)

maybe having a salsa repo. and a github repo. with made-up names and passwords so there is an idea how it looks like ?

I haven't understood what the store bit is all about -

```
git config credential.helper 'store [<options>]'
```

I tried the following from https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage

This is right now just an example with no real credentials, just to understand how it works -

```
shirish@debian:~$ cat .mycredentials 
protocol=https
host=github.com
username=shirish
password=s3cre7
protocol=https
host=salsa.debian.org
username=shirishag75-guest
password=s3cre7   

 $ git config --global credential.helper 'store --file ~/.mycrendials'

 ~$ cat ~/.git.store
cat: /home/shirish/.git.store: No such file or directory
```

what am I missing ?

Comment: Have you read https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage ?

Answer (score 7):

The [format is documented here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store#_storage_format):

> The .git-credentials file is stored in plaintext. Each credential is stored on its own line as a URL like:

```
https://user:pass@example.com
```