# Git credential manager to store credential from salsa.debian.org

Tags: password, git

I am cloning multiple repositories from salsa.debian.org with https, I am wondering how I can use git credential manager to store the password for this site?

Every 100 or so repositories that I clone, it will prompt me for passwords, how can I avoid typing in the password manually?

```
Username for 'https://salsa.debian.org':
Password for 'https://abc@salsa.debian.org'
```

Any input is appreciated. Thank you. I am very new to git credential manager.

I saw a post - [how does ~/git-credentials file look like?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476523/how-does-git-credentials-file-look-like) , but I am trying to clone not just one repo, but multiple repos.